# How to get to file that's uploaded via File Transfer activity

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a Program in MC which has 2 steps, Data Extract activity and File Transfer activity. It ran successfully and I am new and not sure how to access the file. The file location is 'Enhanced FTP' and can anyone tell me how to access that FTP location.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**File Locations**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/administration/filelocations/) are defined in the Administration section.  The base "Enhanced FTP" is typically the **Import** directory.  You can create another **File Location** for the **Export** folder, which is where you extract file will be.

I typically rename them to "Enhanced FTP - Export" and "Enhanced FTP - Import" when working in a new account.

[**FTP Accounts**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/administration/ftpaccounts/) are also defined in the Administration section.

Comment: Thanks. Now my file is available in the new Export folder that I created but I am not able to download to my local directory. If I directly give .zip in filename, it's erroring. Any idea?